# Crash front page, can access any page, only control panel works

Tags: joomla-3.x, front-end, bugs

I need your help, I must revive this site but I don’t know what is going on and it doesn’t work the website. The administration panel works fine.
Any ideas or from where to start

http://www.enpi-medscapes.org/

Comment: Are error messages set to development mode? Global Configuration > Server > Error Reporting

Comment: The htaccess is always a good place to start.  Either remove or replace with core Joomla one to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for your reply. I found the problem, it is a plugin - JA T3 Framework -. I disable it and the website is in the air again.